# C# Winforms Listview Columns sort initially, but does not switch on 2nd click

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, listview

**Scope:** Sort listview by ColumnClick Ascending and/or Descending.

Column click is working and sorts columns Descending, however clicking on the same column, or any column, does not sort Ascending.  Can not figure out out what I am missing.

**ColumnClick Event**

```
        // The column we are currently using for sorting.
    private ColumnHeader SortingColumn = null;

    private void list_ProjectsColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the new sorting column.
        ColumnHeader new_sorting_column = listProjects.Columns[e.Column];

        // Figure out the new sorting order.
        System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder sort_order;
        if (SortingColumn == null)
        {
            // New column. Sort ascending.
            sort_order = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        else
        {
            // See if this is the same column.
            if (new_sorting_column == SortingColumn)
            {
                // Same column. Switch the sort order.
                if (SortingColumn.Text.StartsWith("> "))
                {
                    sort_order = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    sort_order = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // New column. Sort ascending.
                sort_order = System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending;
            }

            // Remove the old sort indicator.
            SortingColumn.Text = SortingColumn.Text.Substring(2);
        }

        // Display the new sort order.
        SortingColumn = new_sorting_column;
        if (sort_order == System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            SortingColumn.Text = "> " + SortingColumn.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            SortingColumn.Text = "< " + SortingColumn.Text;
        }

        // Create a comparer.
        listProjects.ListViewItemSorter =
            new ListViewComparer(e.Column, sort_order);

        // Sort.
        listProjects.Sort();
    }
```

**ListViewComparer Class**

```
    class ListViewComparer : IComparer
    {
    private int ColumnNumber;
    private System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder SortOrder;

    public ListViewComparer(int column_number,
        System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder sort_order)
    {
        ColumnNumber = column_number;
        SortOrder = sort_order;
    }

    // Compare two ListViewItems.
    public int Compare(object object_x, object object_y)
    {
        // Get the objects as ListViewItems.
        ListViewItem item_x = object_x as ListViewItem;
        ListViewItem item_y = object_y as ListViewItem;

        // Get the corresponding sub-item values.
        string string_x;
        if (item_x.SubItems.Count <= ColumnNumber)
        {
            string_x = "";
        }
        else
        {
            string_x = item_x.SubItems[ColumnNumber].Text;
        }

        string string_y;
        if (item_y.SubItems.Count <= ColumnNumber)
        {
            string_y = "";
        }
        else
        {
            string_y = item_y.SubItems[ColumnNumber].Text;
        }

        // Compare them.
        int result;
        double double_x, double_y;
        if (double.TryParse(string_x, out double_x) &&
            double.TryParse(string_y, out double_y))
        {
            // Treat as a number.
            result = double_x.CompareTo(double_y);
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime date_x, date_y;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(string_x, out date_x) &&
                DateTime.TryParse(string_y, out date_y))
            {
                // Treat as a date.
                result = date_x.CompareTo(date_y);
            }
            else
            {
                // Treat as a string.
                result = string_x.CompareTo(string_y);
            }
        }

        // Return the correct result depending on whether
        // we're sorting ascending or descending.
        if (SortOrder == System.Windows.Forms.SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return -result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort things out in ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638760/how-to-sort-things-out-in-listview)

Comment: Wasn't aware I was specifically asking for "How to sort ListView" as it seems apparent the sorting is almost there with above information.   As stated, the issue is the columns are sorting, but clicking on an already sorted column is not switching.

Same shit, different verbiage.